# Multiple Select Default Value

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm using angular 7, I have a form which is going to update a residential so I want to populate it with the residential's data. I have problems with the multiple select, I have

```
<div class="form-group form-default">
   <ng-select [(ngModel)]="residential.sections" name="sections" [ngClass]="'ng-select'" [options]="options" [multiple]="true"></ng-select>
</div>
```

```
residential: Residential;
options = [
        {value: '1', label: 'Clusters'},
        {value: '2', label: 'Códigos'},
        {value: '3', label: 'Directorios'},
        {value: '4', label: 'Documentos'},
        {value: '5', label: 'Propiedades'},
        {value: '6', label: 'Reportes'},
        {value: '7', label: 'Residenciales'},
        {value: '8', label: 'SOS'},
        {value: '9', label: 'Usuarios'}
];
```

The residential.sections is an array like this `[1, 2]`. How do I set the default values? I tried using residential.sections as a simple array `[1,2]` and like a options array

`[{value: '1', label: 'Clusters'},{value: '2', label: 'Códigos'}]`

Comment: Have you tried `["1", "2"]`? Your values are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @IngoBürk Omg thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a default value to residential.sections